# How to automatically load multiple SSH keys on ZSH and PowerLevel10k

Tags: linux, ssh, zsh

I'm trying to have my SSH keys loaded automatically when I start my computer (I'm running Archlinux). At the moment I have to use `ssh-add [PATH]`. I use ZSH, Oh my ZSH and PowerLevel10k.

Here is my `.ssh` folder:

```sh
.ssh
├── config
├── environment-z
├── known_hosts
├── known_hosts.old
├── v_ssh
├── v_ssh.pub
├── z_ssh
└── z_ssh.pub
```

I use the ssh-agent plugin for `ohmyzsh`, with the requested configuration for `PowerLevel10k` :

```sh
[...]
plugins=(git ssh-agent gpg-agent zsh-autosuggestions zsh-syntax-highlighting fast-syntax-highlighting zsh-autocomplete colorize colored-man-pages)

zstyle :omz:plugins:ssh-agent quiet yes
zstyle :omz:plugins:ssh-agent lazy yes

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
[...]
```

And I also have the `.ssh/config` file which contains this :

```
AddKeysToAgent yes
```

Can you tell me how to load my two SSH keys (`z_ssh` and `v_ssh`) at boot time?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround for this.

I created a script `.ssh-add-keys.sh` inside `.ssh` dir

```shell
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cd ~/.ssh

eval $(ssh-agent) > /dev/null

# add all ssh keys
find ~/.ssh -name 'id_*' ! -name '*.pub' -exec ssh-add -q {} \;
```

and put this lines

```shell
# add ssh keys
source  ~/.ssh/ssh-add-keys.sh
```

at the end of `.zshrc`.
Log out - log in
`ssh-add -l` and all my keys are present.

Upd.
If you are on a desktop machine then add these lines

```
Host *
  AddKeysToAgent yes
```

to your `~/.ssh/config` file and once again add your keys to ssh-agent. For now they should be saved in your password manager.

Comment: @فِرجِيل well you right. I just did install zsh and PowerLevel10k on my remote ubuntu machine and yeah ssh-agent plugin doesn't work.

There is even a thread about that https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k/issues/756

But I did a solution and it works.
Updated my answer.

Comment: @فِرجِيل by the way are you adding this to a server or to a desktop machine? If it's desktop then it is a bit easier because a key can be added to a password manager, for example I use Gnome and keys are in a `Seahorse` built-in password manager.

Comment: @فِرجِيل anyway, if you set a password for a key and would like to read it automatically, it seems not quite safe having it saved somewhere in plain text.

Comment: I'm not on a server machine but on a desktop environment. I'm using KDE and normally my config file should register the keys and decode them on login. They only have a password because I often have to transfer them from one machine to another.

Comment: @فِرجِيل if you are on a desktop then try to add this lines 
```
Host *
  AddKeysToAgent yes
```
 into your `~/.ssh/config` file and then one again add your keys to ssh agent and check whether they will persist after rebooting.

Comment: It doesn't work either, every time I open the shell I'm asked for the password to my SSH keys.